# I don't understand this 'for' loop for prime number validation in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, boolean, primes

I don't understand this 'for' loop in Java

This loop is just to check if a number is prime or not. I understand the first statement because 1 is not a prime number but it's what happens in the 'for' statement. Why is 'primeNumber' being divided by two and why is the second 'if' calculating for a remainder of zero? how does this code help to confirm a prime number? what is it doing?

```
public static boolean isPrime (int primeNumber) {

    if (primeNumber == 1) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int primeDivider=2; primeDivider <= primeNumber/2; primeDivider++) {

        if (primeNumber % primeDivider == 0) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Checks if numbers from 2->num/2 divide with no remainders into num (number being tested).

Comment: this question isn't really a great fit for StackOverflow.  Try browsing [http://mathoverflow.net/](http://mathoverflow.net/) or any of many other mathematics resources on the web to learn how prime numbers work.

Comment: How would you determine if a number was prime?  It's almost certainly doing that, with a little optimization.  When checking if 563 is prime, you'd try dividing by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. right?  Only once you've checked if it's divisible by 2, you don't need to check if it's divisible by 563/2 or more, do you?  A hint... you could replace primeNumber/2 with Math.floor( Math.sqrt( primeNumber ))

Comment: Hint: A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.  Think about the relationship between this and `%`.

Answer (score 0):

A prime number can only be divided by itself and one.  7 is prime because only 1 and 7 divide into 7.  Also 8 is not prime because as well as 1 and 8, both 2 and 4 divide into 8.

Look at the `for` loop and see what values `primeDivider` takes: 2, 3, 4, 5, ...  The loop tries each of these in turn to see if it divides into the number you are testing.  If it divides evenly, with a remainder 0, then the number being tested is not prime and the method returns `false`.  If none of the numbers divide, then the number being tested in prime and the method returns `true`.  As an aside, `primeNumber` is a bad variable name.  Something like `possiblePrime` would be better.  The number being tested might not be prime.

The `primeDivider` sequence stops at half the number being tested.  If a number is not prime (a composite number) then at least one of its divisors is guaranteed to be less than or equal to half the number.

As others have said, this is not a very efficient test.  Here is a slightly more efficient version for you to study:

```
public static boolean isPrime (int possiblePrime) {

  // Test negatives, zero and 1.
  if (possiblePrime <= 1) {
    return false;
  }

  // Test even numbers
  if (possiblePrime % 2 == 0) {

    // 2 is the only even prime.
    return possiblePrime == 2;

  } 

  // Test odd numbers >= 3.
  int limit = possiblePrime / 2;
  for (int primeDivider = 3; primeDivider <= limit; primeDivider += 2) {

    if (possiblePrime % primeDivider == 0) {
      return false;
    }

  }

  // Only prime numbers reach this point.
  return true;

}
```

By treating odd and even numbers separately, you can catch all the even numbers with a single test and by stepping `primeDivider` by 2 each time, roughly halve the time taken for odd numbers.

As billjamesdev says, that can be made even more efficient by using:

```
int limit = (int)Math.floor( Math.sqrt( possiblePrime ));
```

A composite number will always have a divisor, other than 1, less than or equal to its square root.